# Contrasts in LMER, one IV

Tags: lme4-nlme, contrasts

I am performing my first LME. In my data set, I have one fixed factor, “Consistency” (3 levels: con, inc, pro). Subject, Passage, and Stim_set are random effects (stim set just contains a particular sequence of passages across the 3 conditions). The dependent variable is RT_target. There are 18 passages (6 in each condition and counterbalanced across stim_set), 30 subjects.
After doing lmer, I want to run 3 pairwise contrasts to assess for significant differences between conditions (con & inc, con & pro, inc & pro).

To do this, I used the following script:

```
m.contrasts <- emmeans(m, "Consistency")
pairs(m.contrasts)
```

Here is the output:

```
 contrast    estimate   SE      df    t.ratio p.value  
 con - inc     -424      56.3    **436**   -7.531  <.0001 
 con - pro     -158      55.9    **438**   -2.826  0.0136 
 inc - pro       266      54.4    **433**    4.887  <.0001 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

I am not certain if I performed the contrasts correctly because the DFs are so high. Are the dfs computed by the total # of observations? The estimate (differences between mean conditions) are correct. In addition, these tests follow the same pattern of differences I got doing ANOVA with contrasts.

Below is the lme output for context:

```
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage) +(1 | Stim_set), Pro2adatFIN); summary(m); Anova(m)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage) + (1 |      Stim_set)
   Data: ProspectdatFIN

REML criterion at convergence: 7379.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0461 -0.6240 -0.1649  0.5549  4.3707 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 183894   428.8   
 Passage  (Intercept)  22943   151.5   
 Stim_set (Intercept)  35019   187.1   
 Residual             241569   491.5   
Number of obs: 480, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 18; Stim_set, 3

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     1715.01     144.02  11.908
Consistencyinc   424.02      56.26   7.537
Consistencypro   158.08      55.88   2.829

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Cnsstncyn
Consstncync -0.205          
Consstncypr -0.207  0.529   
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
                     Chisq    Df   Pr(>Chisq)    
Consistency          58.679    2    1.812e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Maybe one reason the DF appears larger than expected is because all three of your random effects are crossed. If you had nested random effects, the DF used in the K-R corrected T-statistic would be smaller.

Comment: If you run `car::Anova(m)`, look at the df it shows in those results. My guess is they are comparable.